# Playing and Downloading an MP3 file using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, avplayer

I'm currently using the following code to play a mp3 with AVPlayer

```
    NSString *title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://.......com/%@", mp3File];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:title];
    AVPlayerItem *anItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];


    player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:anItem];

    [player play];
```

However I also want to store the downloaded file, so subsequent plays will not require downloading the file again. For this I am using the following

```
     NSString  *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[@"Documents/" stringByAppendingString:surahAyah]];

     if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
     {
        NSString *title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://.......com/%@", mp3File];
        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:title];

        NSData *dbFile = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [dbFile writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
     }
```

What is the best practice for consolidating the above and making using of the cached? AVPlayerItem and storing that instead of making a fresh call to download and save the file?

The MP3 files are approximately 100KB in size, so I'm not too worried about download progress.

Comment: I think the way you use AFNetworking library is still making a fresh call to download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to get this working successfully using the awesome AFNetworking library

```
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

  operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

  [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];


    [operation start];
```